:( correct numb3rs.py passes all test_numb3rs.py checks expected exit code 0, not 1
I have been trying to solve the pset numb3rs.py. All my test cases pass when i run it on my own. But check50 shows me the following error
Results for cs50/problems/2022/python/numb3rs generated by check50 v3.3.11
:) numb3rs.py exists
:) numb3rs.py prints True for 127.0.0.1
:) numb3rs.py prints True for 255.255.255.255
:) numb3rs.py prints True for 140.247.235.144
:) numb3rs.py prints False for 256.255.255.255
:) numb3rs.py prints False for 64.128.256.512
:) numb3rs.py prints False for 8.8.8
:) numb3rs.py prints False for 10.10.10.10.10
:) numb3rs.py prints False for 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
:) numb3rs.py prints False for cat
:( correct numb3rs.py passes all test_numb3rs.py checks
    expected exit code 0, not 1
:| test_numb3rs.py catches numb3rs.py only checking if first byte of IPv4 address is in range
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| test_numb3rs.py catches numb3rs.py accepting expecting five-byte IPv4 address
    can't check until a frown turns upside down

Following is my code for numb3rs.py :
import re
# import sys


def main():
    print(validate(input("IPv4 Address: ")))


def validate(ip):
    ip_matches = re.search(r"^(0|[1-9]\d?|1\d{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"
                           r"\.(0|[1-9]\d?|1\d{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"
                           r"\.(0|[1-9]\d?|1\d{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"
                           r"\.(0|[1-9]\d?|1\d{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$", ip)
    if ip_matches:
        return True
    else:
        return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

